# useCallback with search input field

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm passing an input search component that responsible filtering table results on each key press:

/*Input component*/

```
const SearchInput = useCallback(
  () => (
    <Input
      placeholder="Search"
      onChange={handleSearch}
      defaultValue={Default}
    />
  ),
  [handleSearch, Default]
);
```

/*Box component*/

```
const Box = (children, searchField: SearchField) => (
   <div>
    <span><SearchField /></span>
     {children}
  </div>
 );
```

/*Parent component*/

```
const Parent = () => {
   return {
    <Box searchField={SearchInput}>
      <SomeTableComponent/>
    </Box>
   }
}
```

The issue is when the user start to filter, on each key press the input focus is out, and user can't continue filtering unless he will click on the input again to get focus.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you add what happens inside the `handleSearch` function ? Is it doing something re-renders `SearchInput` or its parents ?

Comment: const handleSearch = useMemo(() => {
    debounced.current = debounce(value => setTerm(value), 100);
    return ({ currentTarget: { value } }) =>
      debounced.current?.(value);
  }, []);

Comment: One probable cause behind this issue could be that your component is mounting and unmounting on every keystroke. Or some other component is taking away the focus. Try using [Event.stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation]) inside the click handler.

Comment: Actually, if I'm passing SearchInput component this way: <Box searchField={SearchInput}> it cause the issue. If I'm passing it as a children it working fine:          <Box ><SearchInput/>
      <SomeTableComponent/>
    </Box>.  I'm just having an hard time to understand why